# How can I open an url file in emacs dired?

Tags: dired, web-browser

When using dired in emacs, how can I open an url file in a web browser outside emacs?

Comment: have you tried `browse-url-at-point`  ?

Comment: Here is a snippet that I could use on OSX (if I wanted to):  `(let ((file (dired-get-file-for-visit))) (start-process "my-process" nil "open" "-a" "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox" file))`.  If you are on a different OS, then you can probably eliminate "open" and "-a", but you may need to add something specific to your OS to ensure that the browser receives input focus (if so desired) -- on OSX, that is what the "-a" is for.  If you want to open multiple files, then you'll need to use `dired-get-marked-files` and loop through the list of marked files.

Comment: @lawlist `browse-url` should be even better for this.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 The OP is actually talking about a file format: http://fileinfo.com/extension/url . The best solution in my mind is http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_open_file_in_ext_apps.html

Comment: Thanks both of you! @lawlist: for some reason I got am error message on your solution, but will not investigate it since I found a perfect solution offered by DoMiNeLa10 and xuhdev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a key binding, such as `C-RET` to open any files in system defined default external programs such as xdg-open on Linux and open on macOS. In this way, URL files are opened by default browsers. A detailed approach is available on ErgoEmacs: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_dired_open_file_in_ext_apps.html

Comment: By the way, how did you bind C-RET? When I tried with this:
             `(global-set-key (kbd "C-return") 'xha-open-in-external-app)` 
I got the error "C- must prefix a single character, not return"

Comment: @myotis `(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'xah-open-in-external-app)`